# setTimeOut not work - it loops badly

Tags: javascript, settimeout, behavior

I want to do a repetitive function that retrieves the selected select's value and sends it to variables

```
 function choosepr(){
var a = document.getElementById("projects");
var b = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;   // get value from select

projectimg(b);
projectbutton(b);
projectdesc(b);

setTimeout(choosepr(),200);   //repeat function after 200ms
}
```

variable "b" takes the correct value and the functions receive it correctly and execute, the problem is with setTimeout, because after activating this function it does not loops with its frequency of 200 ms, it only suspends the computer for some time and stops executing it.

how to fix it and make good loop?

FULL HTML: https://pastebin.com/WVXQrFSf
FULL JS: https://pastebin.com/AAW6wZCt

Comment: `setTimeout(choosepr, 200)`

Comment: This work, really thanks!

Comment: you have to remember, the first argument to setTimeout is a function, not the result of calling a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of going with the `setTimeout` method it's better to use `setInterval` method. This approach  will be more accurate than the `setTimeout` approach, since `setTimeout` waits 200ms, runs the function and then sets another timeout. So the waiting period is actually a bit more than 200ms (or a lot more if your function takes a long time to execute).

Although one might think that `setInterval` will execute exactly every 200ms, it is important to note that `setInterval` will also delay, since JavaScript isn't a multi-threaded language, which means that - if there are other parts of the script running - the interval will have to wait for that to finish.

Try to call this method using `setInterval`.

```
function choosepr(){
var a = document.getElementById("projects");
var b = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;   // get value from select

projectimg(b);
projectbutton(b);
projectdesc(b);
}

setInterval(choosepr, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove the parentheses from `choosepr` because you should not call the function instead you should pass it to `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(choosepr,200);
```

better solution for your case is to use `setInterval`

```
function choosepr()
{
        var a = document.getElementById("projects");
        var b = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;  
        projectimg(b);
        projectbutton(b);
        projectdesc(b);
}

setInterval(choosepr , 200);
```